# Compare arrays of characters in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to compare 2 strings to see if they're equal in assembly. Case sensitive. They're passed in from a cpp wrapper. Here is what I have so far:

I stored one string in esi, the other in edi:

```
LOOP:
    mov al, [esi + edx*4]
    mov bl, [edi + edx*4]
    sub al, bl
    INC edx
    je LOOP
    jmp END_LOOP  ; if it's not equal, do some stuff at the end

END_LOOP:
```

What am I doing wrong? How does it know when I'm at the end of a char array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these strings are C++ strings, and I'm guessing they are made of `char`s and not wide characters, then each character is one byte in size so you should not be multiplying the index register `edx` by 4.  Also, you cannot increment `edx` before *immediately* before your `je` instruction, because that only jumps is edx has been bumped to zero.

Finally, the strings end with a 0 byte.  So you are looking for either `al` or `bl` to be zero to know when to stop your loop.

You can modify your code along these lines:

```
    xor edx, edx         ; make sure edx is 0 to start with
LOOP:
    mov al, [esi + edx]
    mov bl, [edi + edx]
    inc edx              ; prepare for next char
    cmp al, bl           ; compare two current characters
    jne DIFFERENT        ; not equal, get out, you are DONE!
    cmp al, 0            ; equal so far, are you at the end?
    je SAME              ; got to end of both strings, you're good, get out
    jmp LOOP             ; okay well they agree so far, go to next char
DIFFERENT:
    ; Do what you need to do for the strings being different
    ;
    ;
    jmp DONE
SAME:
    ; Do what you need to do for the strings being the same
    ;
    ;
DONE:
```

However I suggest just doing a search for string comparison in x86.  There is a `cmps` instruction.  You can even arrange to call the `strncmp` function if you like.  There are several ways to go about this.

Comment: Strongly second your final paragraph; particularly on _recent_ x86 CPUs string comparison can be done with SSE2 or even the specialized SSE4.2 `pstrcmp` instructions - which is far faster than the simple loop. If you're going for assembly, then do so for a reason :-)

Comment: `repe cmpsb` is *not* efficient.  It only does about 1 compare per clock cycle on modern x86.  `rep stos` and `rep movs`  are the only string instructions that have optimized microcode.  And BTW, this loop is pretty crap.  You could arrange it with a `jne loop` at the bottom, with fall-through to SAME.  Then you have only 2 branches in the loop.  Also, `movzx` would avoid the false dependency.  It's still a byte loop so it sucks a lot anyway (and `rep cmpsb` is better than this loop if you know the length), but SSE2 can go much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Well... why "edx * 4"? Looks like you're only going to be comparing every fourth character. The "sub" sets the flags the same as "cmp". The difference is that "sub" overwrites al, and "cmp" just sets the flags leaving both registers alone. Either should work for you.

Then you "inc edx". This sets the flags again, and you wanted to use the flags to see if the strings are equal! "inc" is kind of a "funny" instruction, in that it sets most of the flags, but leaves the carry flag alone. This isn't going to help you. The "inc" needs to be done, but not between the cmp/sub and the conditional jump!

Unless I'm mistaken, C defines "string" as a zero-terminated array of char, so it's probably safe to ASSume your strings are zero-terminated. An alternative would be to pass in a length as another parameter.

Ray has just posted some nice code that should solve your problem, so I'll stop...

Best,
Frank

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, C doesn't have strings - only character arrays.  The standard library has functions that work with both ASCII and wide characters (including those containing NULL, I believe).