# Assembly x86: comparing strings doesn't work

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to make a program in Assembly that checks two strings.

```
section .data
str1 db 'mystring'
str2 db 'mystring'

output db 'cmp went fine'
len equ $-output

section .text
global main

main:
    mov ecx, str1
    cmp ecx, str2
    je ifBody0
    int 80h

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

ifBody0:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, output
    mov edx, outputlen
    int 80h
```

The weird thing is that when I call the conditional jump: `je [label]`, it doesn't work. But when I change `je` to `jne`, it works.
I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are comparing the addresses of separate string literals?

Comment: @EOF What do you exactly mean? I'm new to assembly. I want to compare the strings.

Comment: Do you know any C, by chance? If so, this is the same error as comparing C-strings by `ptr1 == ptr2` instead of `strcmp(ptr1, ptr2)`.

Comment: @EOF No I don't but how would this be done in assembly?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "strcmp in assembly" or something of that nature?

Comment: So what do you know from programming? (if you don't know C, it may be quite some ride ahead of you, so we need to have some idea where to start with answer). Do you know what is byte? What is computer memory? What is ASCII? What is pointer/address into memory? Can you describe what is CPU register in your own words? And what `mov ecx, str1` does according to you?

Comment: @Ped7g I have programmed in java and python for a while now. But I wanted to learn some more advanced stuff. I know what a byte is: it has 8 bits either a 1 or a 0. ASCII is a collection of symbols, digits, etc. A pointer is an address of something in the memory of the computer and a CPU register is a "segment" in the CPU which you can use to store data, because storing that data in the memory takes a lot more power than, storing it in the registers of the CPU. And 'mov ecx, str1' moves the value of str1 to the ecx-register.

Comment: @EOF I will google it now thanks

Comment: it won't help you if you compare the 2 pointers, you will have to compare the string content, char by char

Comment: @Tommylee2k Can you give an example, or the method to do this. Thanks

Comment: check e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663745/compare-arrays-of-characters-in-x86-assembly note that in the answer the 2 pointers are in SI in DI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For comparing strings in x86-assembly there is a special OpCode named [`CMPS`(Compare Strings)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPS:CMPSB:CMPSW:CMPSD:CMPSQ.html). In your case of BYTE strings the relevant OpCode is `CMPSB`. You do use it by setting `ESI` to the source string and `EDI` to the destination string. The length of the equality check (preferrably the longest string) is set in `ECX`. *Beware of overflows!*.

So your code could look like this:

```
section .data
str1 db 'mystring',0
str1len equ $-str1
str2 db 'mystring',0

output db 'cmp went fine',0x0a,0
outputlen equ $-output
output2 db 'cmp went wrong',0x0a,0
output2len equ $-output2

section .text
global main

main:
    lea esi, [str1]
    lea edi, [str2]
    mov ecx, str1len  ; selects the length of the first string as maximum for comparison
    rep cmpsb         ; comparison of ECX number of bytes
    mov eax, 4        ; does not modify flags 
    mov ebx, 1        ; does not modify flags 
    jne ifWrong       ; checks ZERO flag

ifRight:              ; the two strings do match
    mov ecx, output
    mov edx, outputlen
    int 80h
    jmp exit
ifWrong:              ; the two strings don't match
    mov ecx, output2
    mov edx, output2len
    int 80h
exit:                 ; sane shutdown
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer

Comment: don't forget to specify the direction flag when using cmps

Comment: @Tommylee2k What do you mean with that?

Comment: depending on the direction flag, comps, lods and stos instructions  work either forwards or backwards ( by increasing or decresing SI/DI ) ... you should clear or set it (cld for forward / sed for backward) it before you use the instructions, according to your needs

Comment: In this case the direction flag should be cleared(=forward) by default on entry according to the [intel386-psABI convention, section 2.2.1](https://01.org/sites/default/files/file_attach/intel386-psabi-1.0.pdf): _"The direction flag DF in the %EFLAGS register must be clear (set to “forward” direction) on function entry and return. Other user flags have no specified role in the standard calling sequence and are not preserved across calls."_

Comment: Note that `repe cmpsb` is *not* fast.  Unlike `rep stos` and `rep movs` (memset / memmove) that have "fast strings" microcode, the conditional-rep instructions only go 1 byte at a time internally.  You can do *much* better (like nearly 16x) with SSE2 `pcmpeqb`, see glibc's `strcmp` functions or other examples of vectorized code.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with these two:

```
str1    db 'mystring'
        mov ecx,str1
```

After compiling this with assembler, the raw bytes of machine code looks for example like this (this will become content of memory after loading the executable into it):

```
6D 79 73 74 72 69 6E 67  mystring
B9 00 00 00 00           ¹....
```

The last 4 zeroes are address of 'm' byte from 'mystring', as I decided it will be compiled at address 0. First 8 bytes are the string data (ASCII encoded), `B9` is `mov ecx,imm32` instruction opcode.

You can't put string into `ecx`, `ecx` is 32 bits wide (4 bytes), while string can have many bytes. So with `ecx` you may fetch at most 4 bytes from string, but that would require `mov ecx,DWORD [str1]`, that would put value `0x7473796D` into `ecx` (x86 is little endian, so the first byte `6D` is the least significant in DWORD (32b) value).

But `mov ecx,str1` loads `ecx` with `str1` symbol, which is address of the first `'m'` byte (`0x00000000`).

To compare two strings you load both addresses into some registers, then load the bytes from those addresses, and compare them, one by one, till you find some difference (or end of string) (there are faster algorithms, but they are more complex and require you to know the length of string ahead, while byte by byte compare can work with C-like zero terminated strings easily).

Talking about length of string, you should somehow define one. In C it's common to put zero after last character of string (that would be ahead of `B9` in that example), in C++ `std::string` is structure holding the length as value for direct fetch/compare. Or you can have it hardcoded in source, like your `outputlen`.

When you program in assembler, you should be always aware of how many bits you are processing, and choose correct register size (or extend the value), and correct memory buffer size, to handle the desired value.

With strings that means, that you have to decide upon encoding of strings. ASCII is 8 bit per char (1 byte), UTF-8 has variable number of bytes per glyph, early version of UTF-16 (UCS-2) had 2 bytes per glyph (as Java, but current Utf-16 is variable length), Utf-32 is fixed 4 bytes per glyph. So with ASCII encoded string to fetch it's first character means to do `mov al,BYTE [str1]` (or `mov ecx,str1` `mov al,[ecx]` -> `al = 6Dh = 'm'`) With Utf-32 to fetch second character you would have to do `mov eax,DWORD [utf32str + 4]`. With Utf-8 the single character can have from 1 to 6 bytes at most IIRC, so you have to handle that in quite a complex way, to recognize valid utf-8 code and read correct number of bytes. But if you just want to know if two utf-8 strings are bit-equal, you can compare them byte by byte, without handling glyphs themselves.

Of course you should be aware of sizes of registers and on x86 the way how you can address sub-part of some registers, ie. like `ax` part (lower 16b) out from whole `eax` (32b), or how `ah`:`al` (high 8b : low 8b) form together `ax`.

---

I hope you will understand after this, that you did compare two pointers (`str1` vs `str2`), which will always be unequal, as they point to different byte in memory. Instead of comparing the content in memory (strings).