# Store a string in register

Tags: string, assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to concatenate two strings in assembly language.

```
mov esi, str1
mov eax, str1
mov edx, [str2]
call slen
mov [esi+eax-1], edx
```

[image]

Everything works exactly fine except that only 4 characters of the second string gets appended. I know the reason for its occurrence, but I can't seem to find any solution.

Comment: NASM and microprocessor tags cannot go together.... NASM is for Intel only.

Comment: The solution involves the use of pointers. The book you're using to teach programming should cover that, but you'll have to wait until later. You have to understand integer operations first.

Comment: This may help a little bit to understand "strings" (more like block of data) in ASM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38831846/4271923

Answer (score 3):

You cannot store any string in a register. It has to be equal or smaller than register size (assuming we're talking about ASCII-encoded strings) because a register has a fixed size.