# GNU Assembler can't compare two variables string

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I can't compare two variables string in gnu assembler

```
   mov $[name], %eax            # move name into eax
   mov $[constname], %ebx       # move constname into ebx
   cmp %eax, %ebx               # compare two operands
   je if                        # if
   call else                    # else
```

Comment: That's comparing the addresses, not the data.  Strings are variable length and don't fit in a single register if they're longer than 4 bytes.  That's why `strcmp` is a function in C, not something you can do with `==`.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829719/assembly-x86-comparing-strings-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

Assembly language is a bit different from all other languages, so things don't work the way you are used to in other languages. For example, you can do this in C++ or many other languages:

```
string s = "hello"
string d = "hello"
if (s == d) {}
```

In assembly, you can't do the above because you don't have such nice abstractions available to you to work with. You are close to the machine, so you have to do a lot of the heavy lifting yourself.

Your code doesn't work for a couple of reasons

```
   mov $[name], %eax            # move name into eax
```

The above instruction will move the *address* of `name` into `%eax`. So afterwards when you do:

```
cmp %eax, %ebx
```

It compares two addresses, not "values".

If we, just for example, wanted to `mov` the "value" of our strings into registers, we will write:

```
mov name, %eax
```

Important thing here is that `%eax` can only contain 32-bits(4 bytes) of data. So if your string was "Hello", `%eax` would only contain 4 bytes "olle". Reverse order because of endianness. This greatly limits us but we have other ways to get around it.

We can use `cmpsb`, provided we have a minimum length to work with.

```
#our strings
.data
  name:      .string "Hello"
  constname: .string "Hello"

# other instructions...

   mov $(name), %edi            # move the "Address" of name into edi
   mov $(constname), %esi       # move "Address" of constname into esi
   mov $5, %ecx                 # compare 5 characters only, you can use string1 length here

   rep cmpsb                    # rep `cmpsb` (Compare String Byte), till %ecx is 0
   jz  if                       # Success, jump to if label if zero flag is set
   call else                    # Strings were not equal
# other stuff...

if:                          # if label
```

---

Side note:

I highly recommend you use `$(..)` syntax instead of `$[...]`. AT&T syntax is already riddled with syntactical complexities so let's stick to the most commonly used one. For example `$name`, `$(name)` and `$[name]` all mean the same thing.

Comment: sir/mam did you know how make if else-if in gnu assembler

Comment: There's no simple if else in assembly. There's jumps. You can jump to a certain location. For example, in the code above, `jz if` can jump to a label named '`if`' and start executing code there. `jz` stands for "jump if zero", zero here is the zero flag. If this flag is set to 1, jz will perform a jump. If it is not, next instruction `call else` will be executed. This is how you do if else in assembly. There are a lot jump instructions in assembly, be sure to read them because it is very important to understand them.

Comment: And If this answers your question, accept the answer please.